# How to make a certain page as a homepage in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to make a theme from scratch and make a certain page as a homepage/index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include a `front-page.php` template file with the theme, you can then include all the content you want in that template file.

But when you said, make a certain page as homepage, you may be referring to the `/wp-admin/options-reading.php` [reading settings subpanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel) where the user can set which existing page will be the homepage or the latest blog posts. Note that this will affect the behavior of [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in your `front-page.php` file.

More info can be found in [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) in the WordPress docs and also the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: What's the purpose of index.php?

Comment: @tony `index.php` is default theme file. If you don't provide the other files like `page.php`, `search.php`, `category.php`, etc.; then WordPress will use `index.php`.

Comment: @tony Here is a diagram on how WordPress chooses which template file to use. http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: You can also do it via the Settings>Reading page, but that is a per-instalation fix.

Comment: @jack I mentioned that, yeah.